# CakePHP UTF-8 required direct encoding?

Tags: unicode, utf-8, cakephp-2.0

I wrote an application using CakePHP.
I set everything to use UTF-8 encoding (the database tables, the database connection in database.php, etc.), now I'm wondering whether I should encode every single text string to UTF-8 (with `utf8_encode`) before sending it to the database or it isn't necessary.

Thank you.

Comment: @MozMorris thank you, but why? Does MySQL do it automatically?

Comment: Not automatically. But by specifying the database & connection to be utf8, you'll be safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That isn't necessary.

Specifying the database connection to utf8 will handle the complexities for you. *(see comments)*

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look in [the manual](http://php.net/utf8_encode) for what `utf8_encode` actually does. It *converts* ISO-8859-1 encoded text to UTF-8 encoded text. Yes, it's a horrible name for this function. If your text is not encoded in  ISO-8859-1, you do not need this function. If your text is already in UTF-8, you do not need this function. In short, if you set everything to be UTF-8 from the beginning anyway, it's already UTF-8 and you do not need to do anything else.

Comment: Well, if I send some text from a textarea, is it already UTF-8 or not?

Comment: @Entropy If your site specifies that it's encoded in UTF-8, the browser will send UTF-8 data back to the server. Even more explicitly you can specify the `accept-charset` attribute for forms and set it to UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

It should be the problem of connecting php with mysql database. You can try fix this by making sure that your database server use utf-8 encoding connections by default .

You can force your cakephp application to connect to mysql with utf8 encoding by specifying encoding option in the 
`app/config/database.php`:

```
var $default = array(
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'cakephp',
    'prefix' => '',
    'encoding' => 'utf8'
);
```

You can also force mysql to use utf8 with a query:

SET NAMES 'utf8'

Let me know if you can solve the problem.
Thanks

Comment: then no need to do anything else.